# Proving that S, a subset of V, has the properties of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S = (w1; : : : ; wk) be a subset of V . Prove the following.
(a) If v1 and v2 are in span(S), then v1 + v2 is an element of span(S)
(b) If  α is an element of  F and v is an element of span(S), then   α * v  is an element of span(S)
(d) Conclude that, if S is nonempty, then span(S) is a vector subspace of V .

Could you prove (a) and (b) by proving S is a subspace? I know a subspace would have such qualities, but how do I go about proving that S is a subspace with the information given? I have very little no clue as to how to arrive to the conclusion in (d).

Theorem: If S is any subset of V , the span of S
is the smallest linear subspace of V containing S.

Would you have to prove the above theorem in order to conclude (d)? If so, how would you prove such a theorem?

Comment: If, for example, $V = \mathbb{R}^n$, we know $S$ is not a subspace.  However, $\text{span}(S)$ is a subspace, but this is the fact you are trying to prove.

Comment: How would you go about trying to prove span(S) is a subspace? Would you use some of the linear algebra multiplication and addition axioms or something?

Comment: (a) and (b) together prove that $\text{span}(S)$ is a subspace.  Check your linear algebra textbook for how to prove that a set is a subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of $span(S)$, $v = a_1 w_1 + ... + a_k w_k$ for $v\in span(S)$ and $a_1, ..., a_k \in F$. Then if $v_1, v_2 \in span(S)$, $v_1 + v_2 = (a_1 w_1 + ... + a_k w_k) + (b_1 w_1 + ... + b_k w_k)$
$= (a_1 + b_1)w_1 + ... + (a_k + b_k)w_k \in span(S)$.

Also if $\alpha \in F$ and $v \in span(S)$, then $\alpha * v = \alpha a_1 w_1 + ... + \alpha a_k w_k \in span(S)$. Recall that any subset of a vector space (in this case, $V$) with closure under addition and scalar multiplication is a subspace, which you can verify by going through the properties of vector spaces.

As for the theorem: $S \in span(S)$ (which can be seen by setting the coefficient of a given $w_i$ to $1$ and the others to $0$) and any subspace of $V$ containing $S$ also contains $span(S)$ (by the properties of a vector space), so $span(S)$ is the minimal subspace of $V$ containing $S$.